# How to flash item in ListBox when property changes

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `ListView` which is bound to a `List` of items of the following type:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Both these props have property change notification implemented. Left out for brevity.
    int Price{get;set}
    int Size{get;set}
}
```

I have a `DataTemplate` for this class to show in `ListView`

The size of the list does not change but the values of the properties of the items in the list do. Suppose I first have three items like this:

```
Item format : Size@Price

{(10@34), (15@37), (10@38)}
```

Suppose now the first item only changes due to a data update:

```
{(15@34), (15@37), (10@38)}
```

Please note that I do not remove the existing item. I only change its properties. So a property changed notification will fire for each change. I want to highlight/flash the item that changed in the `ListView` upon such a change. How do I do this (Preferably in XAML)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow this right, Are you just looking to say flash the `ListViewItem` when the `Size` or `Price` property changes?

If so you should be able to do that with a [Binding.TargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event trigger. You do need to make sure your binding for `Size` and `Price` in their binding also specify `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` for this event to fire.

So something like this should work fine:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate" DataType="viewModel:Item">
  <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"
              Background="Transparent"
              Orientation="Vertical">
    <!-- This prolly aint your layout. Just here as an example -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
  </StackPanel>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
          <!-- From="1.0" helps prevent spam property changes skewing the opacity -->
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="stackPanel"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                           From="1.0"
                           To="0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Alternate:**

From blend with `xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"`
you should also have `<ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>` using which you can then say invoke a Behavior to trigger a `Storyboard` `<ei:ControlStoryboardAction>`. Personally I've only used the first approach as it's slightly simpler.

Comment: @nakiya so did you actually try it?